# vertical align center input and button in div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a search setup inside a div but for some reason cannot get it to vertically align center

This is my code -

HTML:

```
<div class="search">
<input class="searchfield" type="text" placeholder="Search..." value="" />&nbsp;<button class="searchbutton">SEARCH</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search{
padding 0 10px;
font-size:0.8em;
float:right;
height:100%;
display:table;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.searchfield{
display:table-cell;
}

.searchbutton{
display:table-cell;
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks vertically centered to me: http://jsfiddle.net/5cyPs/

Comment: yeah I thought it would center but it doesn't. I inspected the .search div with Firefox - Firebug and it has plenty of height for the button and input to move in but nothing is happening... annoying

Comment: Looks fine to me but you can play with line-height and see if works for you

Comment: Thanks UmairP line-height worked for me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a line-height equal to your font-size.

```
.search{
  padding 0 10px;
  font-size:0.8em;
  **line-height: 0.8em;**
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  display:table;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```